# Could not parse as assignation expression: "${attrs ?: defaultAttrs}"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

What am I missing with the following thymeleaf markup:

```
<tr th:fragment="row" th:with="defaultAttrs='placeholder=\'' + ${placeholder} + '\''">                            
    <td>
        <input th:attr="${attrs ?: defaultAttrs}" />
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

called from

```
<th:block th:include="row::row(attrs='value=\'*{prodName}\', minLength=\'.{2, 16}\', required, title=\'starts with an alphabet 2 and 8\' placeholder=\'Product name\'')" />
```

which is producing this error:

```
Could not parse as assignation sequence: "${attrs ?: defaultAttrs}"
```

On an unrelated note, had to do a double take at the exception message for the interesting usage of the word assignation instead of assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass text string to `th:attr`. Thymeleaf expects expression, but not string. Next example will NOT work, but this what you're trying to do:

```
<input th:attr="${'placeholder=\'defaultPlaceholder\''}" />
```

I suggest you next way:

```
<tr th:fragment="row" th:with="defaultPlaceholder='placeholder', defaultMaxlength=10">                            
    <td>
        <input th:attr="placeholder=${placeholder?:defaultPlaceholder},
            maxlength=${maxlength?:defaultMaxlength}" />
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

It looks longer, but gives you more control for manage attributes.

---

**Updated**: If you prefer pass all attributes in one string variable, you can use Thymeleaf's [preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing). For example, next code, is how you going to use fragment in your page:

```
<div th:include="fragment :: row(attrs='value=\'*{prodName}\', minLength=\'.{2, 16}\', 
    required=true, title=\'starts with an alphabet 2 and 8\', placeholder=\'Product name\'')">
```

Then you fragment will something like this:

```
<div th:fragment="row"> 
    <div th:with="defaults='placeholder=\'placeholder\', maxlength=10'" th:remove="tag">
        <tr>                            
            <td>
                <input th:if="${attrs!=null}" th:attr="__${attrs}__"/>
                <input th:if="${attrs==null}" th:attr="__${defaults}__"/>
            </td>
            ...        
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanations:

- main tag of fragment will NOT be included in result page. So, don't use `<tr>` as main tag. Instead, wrap `<tr>` into `<div>`.
- parameters passed to fragment will override all variables declared in `th:with` of main tag of fragment. So, if you would like to pass any parameters to fragment, don't declare `th:with` right in main tag of fragment. Do it the body of fragment.
- if you don't need to output some tags in result page, just use `th:remove` [attribute](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#removing-template-fragments). This attribute allows you to remove parts of fragment. In this example we used second `<div>` just to declare `th:with` and we don't need this `<div>` in result page.

---

You have error in `attr` paramter of `th:include`. Because attribute is pair of name and value, you can't specify just `required`. You have to write: `required=true`. Another one error: you missed comma between `title` and `placeholder`. Correct string should be next:

```
<th:block th:include="row::row(attrs='value=\'*{prodName}\', minLength=\'.{2, 16}\', 
    required=true, title=\'starts with an alphabet 2 and 8\', placeholder=\'Product name\'')" />
```

Comment: The th:attr property value would only be known at runtime. It will be passed as a parameter named "attrs" to the row fragment. Is there a way to pass the needed expression as a parameter and also to store it as a variable?

Comment: @000 You can use Thymeleaf's preprocessing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I attempted but got: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "\_\_${attr}\_\_" I have added the th:include call to the row fragment with the attr parameter to the question

Comment: @000 you've errors in value of `th:include`. look at update.

Comment: I used your updated th:include attribute instead and still got the same exception message

Comment: @000 did you declared `attrs` parameter for fragment? something like: `th:fragment="row (attrs)"`

Comment: I did not use the approach of declaring the fragment parameters. That is because thymeleaf required that arguments be supplied for all declared parameters. I want the user to be able to ignore optional parameters if they want

Comment: @000 actually, Thymeleaf is much more convenient and has much more readable code. You just have to learn how to use it properly. Take a look for update in answer.